# Sed search and replace path in xml file

Tags: replace, sed

can anyone help me?

I am trying to write a shell script that searches an XML file for a path:

```
<string>User/MyUser/Library/Folder/File.txt<string>
```

Then replaces that path with another path:

```
<string>/Library/CustomFolder/CustomFile.txt<string>
```

The path that I am searching for is variable but will always contain the word Library.

Is there any way to search for `>*/Library` and replace it with  `>/Library`

I would then like to search for  `Library*<` and replace it with `Library/CustomFolder/CustomFile.txt<`

Please read the above as though the * character refers to any string...

I am currently trying to get there using `sed -i` (because I want to edit the file itself not just the standard output) but I am a bit of a noob and I keep getting an error when trying to test it.

So far I have:

```
sed -i 's/Library/TEST/g' ~/Library/Path/To/MyFile.xml
```

This returns an extra characters at the end of l command error so I haven't gotten to trying to work out the * bit yet...

Is there a better way of doing this or am I just doing it wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Mattus

Comment: could you post your exact error message? What OS and shell are you using (e.g. Linux and bash or Windows and Cygwin)

Answer (score 2):

It can get a little hard and complicated when you try to modify your xml file 
with only sed/awk utilities. If you need to make some more complex xml modifications 
this solution may help you out:

If you can install some software on your machine then you could try:

XMLStarlet: http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/

After the installation you can the edit your file like this:

`$>./xmlstarlet ed -u '/xml/table/rec[@id=1]/numField' -v 42 xml/myfile.xml`

Of course this tool allows you to do more complex tasks than just edit a single
value of a xml element. Which can become very useful one day.

A list of complete commands/features can be found here:

http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/xmlstarlet.txt

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding that it is not the best way to edit an XML file using a line based editor (as `sed` is) you could e.g. do this:

```
sed -i.bak 's/>[^>]*Library/>Library/;s#Library[^<]*<#Library/CustomFolder/CustomFile.txt<#' ~/Library/Path/To/MyFile.xml
```

`sed -i.bak` will do an inplace edit of *MyFile.xml* saving a backup of the original file in *MyFile.xml.bak*.
I used two `s` commands one (`s/>[^>]*Library/>Library/`) replacing `>` followed by any number of characters other than `>` including a following `Library` string with `>Library`.
The other one (`s#Library[^<]*<#Library/CustomFolder/CustomFile.txt<#` replaces the string `Library` followed by any number of characters != `<` followed by a `<` with `Library/CustomFolder/CustomFile.txt<`. Please notice that I used `#` instead of the usual `/` to avoid the necessity to escape the `/` characters in the replacement string.

Comment: Any idea what is causing that? i am trying to test through terminal on snow leopard...

Comment: Do you have spaces in your file name? If yes - did you quote the name? What's the actual line you are trying to execute?

Comment: sed -i.bak ~/Library/Preferences/TemporaryXMLpreference.xml 's/>[^>]*Library/>Library/;s#Library[^<]*<#Library/ColorSync/Profiles/"CustomProfile.icc"<#'

Comment: i think there may be spaces in the * path that is being replaced... would that make any difference?                                                         sed -i.bak ~/Library/Preferences/TemporaryXMLpreference.xml 's/>[^>]*Library/>Library/;s#Library[^<]*<#Library/ColorSync/Profiles/CustomPro‌file.icc<#'                                  does not seem to help...

Comment: It doesn't matter if there are spaces in the pattern to be replaced. Actually I wonder where `sed` sees an `l` command as mentioned in the error message. Just to be sure - what does your `~` expand to (execute `echo ~`)?

Comment: When i echo ~ i get /Users/MyUser

Comment: The Full error message is "sed: 1: "/Users/MyUser/Libra...": extra characters at the end of l command"

Comment: @Mattus: It seems that my syntax was not fully correct (resp. at least works not with every `sed` version - cannot verify at the moment). Therefore I changed my post.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
sed -i '' 's/Library/TEST/g' ~/Library/Path/To/MyFile.xml
```

I think the -i option is gobbling your 's' command thinking its the back-up extension

(just had and fixed the same problem)